# Am I able to use two mice in my Ubuntu desktop?

Tags: mouse, touchpad, acer, multi-touch, mouse-pointer

I'm using an Acer laptop, and Ubuntu 19.04. 
I want to use my laptop touchpad and my wireless mouse separately with two cursors.

Comment: Please explain "two cursors". The last pointing device used steals focus from the previous pointing device, so there is only one cursor visible. For example if you move the mouse, the mouse cursor gets the focus and is visible. Is that what you mean by "two cursors" or do you mean two cursors visible at the same time and you can use either one?

Comment: Does this matches your request (since it can be also done on Ubuntu): https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multi-pointer_X

Comment: [Like this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multi-pointer_X)?

Comment: @TomBrossman I had did like the article and now I can control two mouses, but my secondary mouse keeps on blinking

Comment: https://ibb.co/cTvckYQ here the image